# C# Insertion sort List (ascending + descending)

Tags: c#, list, sorting, unity-game-engine, insertion-sort

I am developing a game in Unity, c#.
I have a large Vector3 list of 16k elements that has holds x position, y for dic key and z position.

The list gets sorted very often but only 2750 of that list gets sorted and the rest remains unsorted.

Right now I am using  linq for a quickstort with  orderby:
list = list.OrderBy(x => x).ToList
But it is not the right sort algorithm for my case.

I have no idea how to implement an Insertion sort for a Cector3 list. Just did it with simple arrays. Is there maybe an Insertion sort (ascending and descending) for Vector3 list already in linq?

Comment: "But it is not the right sort algorithm for my case." - can you say more about your analysis here? What makes insertion sort a better fit than quicksort, in your mind?

Comment: Also `but only 2750 of that list gets sorted and the rest remains unsorted` .. how do you determine which ones you want to sort?

Comment: In the list I only need to access the first 2750  or the last 2750. The x and z positions of those element change (it is a big real time tiling script)
So a huge part (over 80%) is sorted and I know in the script if it is the first 80% or last 80%.
Thats why I thought that insertion sort might fit better because it needs to insert the remaining 18-20% into the already sorted part.

Comment: you can use linq `Take` and `Skip` to only sort a specific amount and then copy those back into your array

Comment: You can also write your own comparison method if the norm is not right

Comment: how can you do that?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have 16,000 Vector3s, but you only need to sort the first or last 2750 elements, yes?

Comment: Almost yeah. 
16k V3,  but only  2750 get dirty. Thats why I thought that with an insertion sort you have already have 13k elements sorted and insert the 2750 in the right place.
My brother suggested me quick select. Thoughts on that?

Answer (score 0):

Well turns out insertion sort is worse.

Thats how I wrote it:

```
    static void sortVec3Array(Vector3[] arrayToSort, int startAt, int stopAt)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = startAt+1; i < stopAt; i++)
    {
        float item = arrayToSort[i].x;
        int ins = 0;
        for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && ins != 1;)
        {
            if (item < arrayToSort[j].x)
            {
                arrayToSort[j + 1].x = arrayToSort[j].x;
                j--;
                arrayToSort[j + 1].x = item;
            }
            else ins = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Came across Tim Sort which is kinda what I need.

I implemented it and it works like a charm.  Ms is like 1.4 - 1.9 which is 3 times faster than the .Orderby algorithm and now useable for me.

Comment: found a real port to c#   by an open project.  Ms down to 0.3  - 0.4 ....